# Creating a model object with a M2M and FK relationship

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following model --

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Credit(models.Model):
    person = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    credits = models.ManyToManyField(Credit)
```

I have created the following `Category` and `Credit` objects --

```
>>> Category.objects.create(category='animation')
>>> Category.objects.create(category='drama')
>>> Credit.objects.create(person='john', position='director')
>>> Credit.objects.create(person='tom', position='writer')
```

I then 'get' those four objects --

```
>>> cat1 = Category.objects.get(category='animation')
>>> cat2 = Category.objects.get(category='drama')
>>> cred1 = Credit.objects.get(person='john')
>>> cred2 = Credit.objects.get(person='tom')
```

But I'm having difficulty creating the `Video` object. How would I create the following two objects?

```
1) Video.objects.create(title='little italy', category=cat1, credits=cred1)  ??
2) Video.objects.create(title='new film', category=cat2, credits=cred1, cred2)  ??
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#saving-foreignkey-and-manytomanyfield-fields).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> v1 = Video.objects.create(title='little italy', category=cat1)
>>> v1
<Video: little italy>
>>> v1.credits.add(cred1)
```

...etc...