# Troubles with Many-to-Many & Save customization

Tags: python, django

I Have two classes: **Story** and **XmlLink**. And there is many-to-many relationship between them.
I'm trying to customize saving method of XmlLink. 
Idea: when I added new xmllink-object, a new story-object (temp) creates some records in db. But also I need to customize **.story** in *def save* to replace m-to-m relations with, for example, (6,7)

```
class Story(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  content = models.TextField()

class XmlLink (models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
  story = models.ManyToManyField(Story)
  pk = 1

  def save(self):
    **self.story = (6,7)**

    temp = Story(title = 'temp',
        content = 'testtttt',
    temp.save()
    super(XmlLink, self).save()
```

i'm tried to search some examples, and different ways to solve this, but ... 
Maybe someone can simplify the procedure?

Answer (score 0):

This may be of some help in how to save a M2M relationship in django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many.

I find that it's usually more straightforward and easier to save it directly in the view, rather than defining a save method on the model.

Also, this answer may be of help: [Creating a model object with a M2M and FK relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170583/creating-a-model-object-with-a-m2m-and-fk-relationship/6170694#6170694).